# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/AbstractDriverOptions - Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium4, selenium-edgedriver

**Hi,
I tried all possible solutions but I am keep getting exception.My requirement is to use EdgeOptions to add extension in browser before running scripts for that I am using Selenium 4.x.x**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.AbstractDriverOptions
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

**Please can review my pom.xml dependencies if I am using incorrect dependencies or any version mismatch**

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chromium-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chromium-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
         
   
 
         
    </dependencies>
```

***Here it is my code , here driver is getting initialized I am getting exception in constructor of EdgeOptions .Code is all correct no where null is passing.***

```
public static WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        Properties prop = ConfigTestData.prop;
        String browser = prop.getProperty("proj.browser");
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", prop.getProperty("proj.browser.driver.exe.path"));

            ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
            opt.addArguments("--log-level=2");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);  
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", prop.getProperty("proj.browser.driver.exe.path"));
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();

            driver = new EdgeDriver(options);//getting here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Mentioned driver does not exist.Please set either chrome or MS edge");
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: Carefully look at your dependencies `ClassNotFoundException` usually mean they're not correct.